# window.open to pass parameters to php and trigger pdf creation and view

Tags: php, pdf, post, window.open

I've been using window.open to point to a php file where I create a pdf on the fly using fpdf and display it immediately to the user. Seems to work fine across all browsers and even mobile devices. For example:

```
window.open('/client/feature_Schedule/scheduleReport.php','Schedule_Report','width=900,height=600,status=yes');
```

I'm not passing any values in this example because all of the parameters needed already exist in the php file.

But now I'd like to pass values from javascript along in order to query of the database in the php file before creating the pdf and displaying it to the user. Is there a convention I should be aware of? Window.open doesn't seem to handle this except by adding the values after "?" at the end of the url. But I'd prefer to POST the values because there could be a lot of data being sent to the php file. I've even been playing around with $.ajax but am not sure how to trigger with pdf to open for the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does "a lot of data" mean?  Many parameters?  Long parameters?

Comment: The length of the parameters string being sent could be quite long. If 7000+ characters is the max for a url (which I'm not sure), then the length of the url could be much longer. That's why I'd wish to use POST instead. Does that sound like the right logic?

Comment: Also, I'll be working on applying your answer below as well as the others. Great forum! I appreciate the quick responses. Don't know what's taken me so long to use it. Will give some feedback when/if successful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to send POST data with window.open() and it is quite simple:
[Window.open and pass parameters by post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951768/window-open-and-pass-parameters-by-post-method-problem)

It can even be made without any actual HTML code involved just with pure javascript programming.

// Edit: added javascript only solution:

```
<input type="button" value="Open" onclick="openWindow();" />
<script>
function openWindow(){
    // create <form>
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.action = 'process.php';
    form.target = 'window_1'; // target the window
    // append it to body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(form);
    // create an element
    var child1 = document.createElement('input');
    child1.type = 'text'; // or 'hidden' it is the same
    child1.name = 'elem1';
    child1.value = 'some value';
    // append it to form
    form.appendChild(child1);
    // create another element
    var child2 = document.createElement('input');
    child2.type = 'text'; // or 'hidden' it is the same
    child2.name = 'elem2';
    child2.value = 'some other value';
    // append it to form
    form.appendChild(child2);

    // create window
    window.open('', 'window_1');

    // submit form
    form.submit();
    body.removeChild(form); // clean up
}
</script>
```

Comment: Good question @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. I was able to follow the logic of the link Ivan posted and it resolved my issue. Not as clean an approach as I was hoping for but it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and ryan77 I have added javascript only solution... hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `<form>` with hidden inputs and use JavaScript to submit the form.  Notice the `target="_blank"` attribute which causes the form to post to a new window.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['pdfForm'].submit();return false;">Generate PDF</a>

<form target="_blank" id="pdfForm" name="pdfForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="val1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="val2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.open()` can only perform GET requests. You will need to [create a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003089/dynamically-create-and-submit-form) with the appropriate controls and target if you want to have the same effect with POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP you can simply include the parameters in the GET statement

```
window.open('/client/feature_Schedule/scheduleReport.php?parameter='.$value,'Schedule_Report','width=900,height=600,status=yes');
```