# jQuery create and submit form dynamically

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create and submit a form through code. What's wrong with the below?

```
$('#btnPrintInvoicePerFile').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //stop link default

    var componentInvoiceId = EberlsComponentInvoiceForm.componentInvoice.Id;
    console.log(componentInvoiceId);

    $('<form>', {
        "id": "getInvoiceImage",
        "html": '<input type="text" id="componentInvoicId" name="componentInvoicId" value="' + componentInvoiceId + '" />',
        "action": window.siteRoot + 'ComponentInvoice/GetInvoiceImage/'
    }).submit();

});
```

Comment: You might want to look at jQuery .post http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ instead.  It's probably closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: " What's wrong with the below?" I dunno, what errors are you getting? What's not happening that you think should be happening?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try to append the form to the body element first:

```
$('<form>', {
    "id": "getInvoiceImage",
    "html": '<input type="text" id="componentInvoicId" name="componentInvoicId" value="' + componentInvoiceId + '" />',
    "action": window.siteRoot + 'ComponentInvoice/GetInvoiceImage/'
}).appendTo(document.body).submit();
```

Comment: ah, gotta appendTo body first. This worked! Is it worth removing from the body after submit?

Comment: @Mark No, because the page will unload then the form is submitted.