# codeigniter and pay-pal - nothing happens on click

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, paypal

I am using a Pay-pal plugin for codeigniter [found here](http://code.google.com/p/codeigniter-myproject/source/browse/trunk/application/libraries/Paypal_Lib.php?spec=svn111&r=111) codeigniter 2.0+, php 5.3.13 with apache 2.2.22. Is this plugin out-dated ?

So this I what I have and what is the problem.

```
private function getPayPalForm( $first_name, $last_name, $amount, $registration_id ){
    $this->load->library('Paypal_Lib');        
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', site_url('/register/success/'));
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', site_url('/register/cancel/'));
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', site_url('/register/ipn/'));
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', $registration_id);
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', 'Registration ID - '.$registration_id." for ".$first_name." ".$last_name);
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', $registration_id );
    $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount', $amount);
    return $this->paypal_lib->paypal_form();
}
```

This is the function being called from the plugin

```
function paypal_form($form_name='paypal_form') 
{
    $str = '';
    $str .= '<form method="post" action="'.$this->paypal_url.'" name="'.$form_name.'"/>' . "\n";
    foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value)
        $str .= form_hidden($name, $value) . "\n";
    $str .= '<p>'. $this->submit_btn . '</p>';
    $str .= form_close() . "\n";

    return $str;
}
```

All the information is coming out in the correct places on my custom view. Here is that view.

```
<div>
       <div class="innerwidget">
        <div class="bubble">
            <div class="rectangle"><span>Make Payment</span></div>
            <div class="triangle-l"></div>
            <div class="triangle-r"></div>
            <div class="info">
                <p>Hari Om <?php echo $firstname; ?>, you are almost done.</p>
                <p> To make your payment, please click the Pay-Pal button below.</p>

<div class="form-button-container">
    <?php echo( $paypal_form ); ?>
    <p style="font-size: 12px; color:blue;"> <b>Check out with Paypal to pay by Paypal Account or credit card.</b></p>
</div>  

            </div>
        </div>
     </div> 
</div>
```

All of this is working fine, **the problem is**, when I click on my button nothing happens. I am not forwarded off to pay-pal. I am loading jquery libraries a part of my base template head section. Are these libraries conflicting ?

Here is the fire bug output.

```
<div class="form-button-container">
 <form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paypal_form"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mymail@gmail.com" />
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.mydomain.org/successFunction" />
   <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.mydomain.org/cancelFunction />
   <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.mydomain.org/ipn" />
   <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1375" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2013 Annual Banquet - 2 persons" />
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50" />
  <p> <input type="image" name="add" src="https://www.mydomain.org/assets/images/buttons/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" border="0" /></p>
  </form>
  <p style="font-size: 12px; color:red;"> <b>Check out with Paypal to pay by Paypal Account or credit card.</b></p>
</div>
```

This is my very first time using pay-pal and I am totally stumped.

EDIT:
Should I adjust the plugin to say input type as submit instead of image? That is how the plugin came.

```
function image()
{
    $this->submit_btn = '<input type="image" name="add" src="' . base_url() . 'images/paypal-button.png" border="0" />';
}
```

Comment: unless paypal have changed the way the form submission needs to work the library should be working fine. What are you clicking on the 'Add' image? If so it might be because the browser does not know what to do when you click on the image. You might need to create some JS to assign an action to it <- because there is no submit button

Comment: Pls add submit button after <?php echo( $paypal_form ); ?>

Comment: I tried that which I outlined in my edit...not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok in the event someone else is having similar issues. I was using jquery ajax to post to my action. That action returns the HTML which I simply empty and append to the body. **BIG MISTAKE**  I used http://www.avramovic.info/razno/jquery/redirect/ to do a redirect in a jquery stye and it worked perfectly. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036684/jquery-redirect-with-post-data) as well

```
        $.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>register/finish", mydataobject, function(data){
              //bla bla
        });
```

Now all I am doing is

```
$().redirect('<?php echo base_url();?>register/finish', mydataobject);
```

Hope it helps someone in need

Answer (score 0):

I would say, yes, it's out-dated.  The copyright on it is 2006.

I don't mean to simply plug my own thing, but since you're using CodeIgniter I'd recommend using my [CI Library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/).  I maintain it and it's worked very well for lots of different developers for years now.

Now, my library doesn't include Payments Standard, which is what you're using here, but it does include Express Checkout (and nearly every other API PayPal provides) which is the API version of a Standard checkout form.

Express Checkout consists of SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  It's a little bit more work, but it has fewer limitations than what Payments Standard has, and it will free you up to do different things within your checkout experience that you can't do with the Standard Payments integration.

For example, with Payments Standard, there is no guarantee the user will end up back on your site, even if you have Auto-Return enabled in your PayPal account profile.  The redirect takes 5 - 10 seconds, and the user could (and often does) close the browser before the redirect happens.

With Express Checkout the user will always end up back at your site prior to completing the checkout flow, so you can handle things within checkout much easier.