# ajax returns variable from next page, but it's not actually there on arrival

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting a variable via ajax from index.php to home.php. If there is success, I echo back the variable (userID). Otherwise, I echo "Noone". On index.php, I receive an alert with "user:1" + a bunch of other garbage from the page. Neverminding the garbage, which is the rest of the page's contents for some reason (a previous question I asked didn't seem to answer this), it seems the post worked. However, when I actually load the home.php, "Noone" is printed out at the top of the page, which of course destroys all of my queries. Any suggestions? Thanks for checking this out.

index.php:

```
$.ajax({
url: "home.php",
type: "POST",
data: {uName:uid},
datatype: "text"
}).success(function(data){
    alert("user:" + data);
    window.location.replace("home.php");
});
```

home.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uName'])){
    $curUser = $_POST['uName']; 
}
else
    $curUser = 'Noone';
echo $curUser;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>...
```

Comment: `window.location.replace("home.php");` makes a GET request, not a POST request. Hence `$_POST['uName']` cannot be set. Maybe you are looking for a way to persist data on the server side between requests. Have a look at sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am just looking into this now, but if I am worried about people rejecting cookies, is there an alternative?

Comment: You can send the data you need via `GET`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New page is not loading when using a Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948754/new-page-is-not-loading-when-using-a-session)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answer by referencing another post, [jQuery - Redirect with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036684/jquery-redirect-with-post-data), which recommended installing the jquery.redirect.min.js plug-in. The extra garbage was still echoed, but the data passed and my queries worked. My final code was this:

index.php:

```
$.ajax({
url: "home.php",
type: "POST",
data: {uName:uid},
datatype: "text"
}).success(function(data){
    alert("user:" + data);
    $().redirect('home.php', {'uName': data});
});
```

home.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uName'])){
    $curUser = $_POST['uName']; 
}
else
    $curUser = 'Noone';
echo $curUser;
?>
```