# New page is not loading when using a Session

Tags: php, session

I am trying to pass a php session from one page to the next. However, when I load the 2nd page, the url changes, but the 1st page reloads. Nothing from the 2nd page appears whatsoever. I feel like it is the isset line that is messing this up, but I may be wrong. Any ideas as to where I may be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

page 0 html:

```
<div id="login">
<p>Username:
    <input type="text" id="loginName" Required>
</p>
<p>Password:
    <input type="password" id="loginPass" Required>
</p>
<span id="loginError">Please enter a username AND password</span>
```

page 0 jquery(This uses the redirect plugin):

```
$("#login").dialog({
modal: true,
buttons: {
    Login: function(){
        var userName = $("#loginName").val();
        var userPass = $("#loginPass").val();                                                           
        var request1 = $.ajax({ 
            url: "indexDb.php", 
            async: true, 
            type: "POST", 
            data:{uName:userName, uPass:userPass, func:1},
            dataType: "html" 
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data == "Password Not Found"){
                //alert(data);
                $("#loginError").text("The password you entered was incorrect");
                $("#loginError").show();
            }
            else if(data == "Name Not Found"){
                $("#loginError").text("The username you entered was not found");
                $("#loginError").show();
            }   
            else{                                       
                uid = data;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "home.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {uName:uid},
                    datatype: "text"
                }).success(function(data){
                    alert("user:" + data);
                    $().redirect('home.php', {'uName': data});
                });             
            }                   
        })//end success                             

    } //end of login button

} //end of buttons
}); //end of dialog
```

page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['uName'])){
    $_SESSION['currentID'] = $_POST['uName'];
    $curUser = $_POST['uName'];
}
?>
<html>
    <a href="page2.php">page 2</a>
</html>
```

page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['currentID']."hi";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['uName']` is set and therefor a session variable gets setted? For debugging reason set after `session_start();` your session variable to a defult value `$_SESSION['currentID'] = 'not set';`

Comment: Yes it is set. I added a test to echo "true" if isset and "false" if not, and it returned true

Comment: I've checked your code works fine with me...

Comment: can you post the code of form from which you are submitting your uName?

Comment: There is a lot more written on the pages. Could it be something within the rest of this context that's causing the problem?

Comment: i changed your `$_POST` to `$_GET` and passed a QueryString to uName and it works, you need to double check your form are you realling submitting your form with POST and uName field?

Comment: If you can just upload your form and uName field markup then perhaps someone can help you...

Comment: There was no form. The user enters in a jquery dialog box, the data is passed thru an ajax call where the userID is returned from a database, and then the userID is passed on via POST to the next page.

Comment: How does the AJAX request get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

`$().redirect('page1.php', {'uName': data});` what do you mean by this? all you have to do is to create a request for page1 one using a click or some other event, then create another ajax request for page2 and check your response. Try this jquery code.

```
$('#check').click(function()
{
    //Submit the form
    $.ajax({
        url: "page1.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {uName:"Your Name"},
        datatype: "text"
        }).success(function(data){
            alert("user:" + data);
            $.ajax({
                url: "page2.php",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "text"
                }).success(function(data){
                    alert("Page2:" + data);

                });
        });
});
```

and this to your html

```
<div id = "check">Trigger</div>
```

So when you click on "trigger" JQuery dispatch a request for page1 there you set your session, in the JQuery callback of first request you create another request for page 2 and you get your page 2 response.

Comment: The first Ajax request is a call to the database to check that the user exists. In the second one, redirect is a plugin that sends you to the new page plus posts your data. What you are suggesting is no different that  what I did since I said is my session is set.