# When trying to use windows.location.href , the values of $_POST[''] is lost

Tags: javascript, php

This is my php script

```
    switch($x[0]){
        case 'categorias' :
                    $_POST['step'] = 'categorias';
                    $_POST['pais']=$_POST['pais'];
                    $_POST['method']=1;
                    ?><script>
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo $url ?>?step=categorias";
                    </script><?
                    break;
        case 'corredores':
                    $_POST['step'] = 'corredores';
                    $_POST['pais']=$_POST['pais'];
                    $_POST['method']=1;
                    ?><script>
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo $url ?>?step=corredores";
                    </script><?
                    break;
        default: //do something ;
}
```

When I am trying to do this I am loosing the values that I am sending using POST[''] variable ,

Can any one help me out with this , I tried using the php `header()` option but it is producing header already sent error,

So i used the  javascript

Can any one help me how I can fix this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to repost these values using a form. Or you can use Session or cookies.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't generally be _setting_ `$_POST` values. Second, even if that whole concept worked, `window.location.href` performs a `GET` request. You need to either put the values into `$url` or output a form with the required POST values in it and submit the form with javascript

Comment: @madforstrength okay so I need to add an HTML form tag inside the case statement and send it , this is what you mean ? .

Comment: you will loose it as `window.location.href` works like you browse any page by just passing URI in address bar. You can pass your data in querystring if it is not big

Comment: If you use form than you need to submit it programatically instead of using `location.href`. for example `document.form1.submit();`

Comment: @vikas I am trying to modify a application that has 2000 lines of code they have used $_Post[''] and validated most of the part changing all to get will be a big task , :(

Comment: then you should perform a POST operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already answerd here [jQuery - Redirect with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036684/jquery-redirect-with-post-data#answer-23347795)

```
var redirect = 'Your Url here';
$.redirectPost(redirect, {x: 'example', y: 'abc'}); // your parametters

// jquery extend function
$.extend(
{
    redirectPost: function(location, args)
    {
        var form = '';
        $.each( args, function( key, value ) {
            form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
        });
        $('<form action="'+location+'" method="POST">'+form+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: is that two different method to do this task ? .

Comment: Watch out, this is XSS vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, `$_POST` should not be set manually but generated by submitting a `form`.
You can add the `values` to the URL like this:

```
switch($x[0]){
    case 'categorias' :
                $step = 'categorias';
                $pais = $_POST['pais'];
                $method = 1;
                ?><script>
                window.location.href = "<?php echo $url ?>?step=$step&pais=$pais&method=$method";
                </script><?
                break;
    case 'corredores':
                $step = 'corredores';
                $pais = $_POST['pais'];
                $method = 1;
                ?><script>
                window.location.href = "<?php echo $url ?>?step=$step&pais=$pais&method=$method";
                </script><?
                break;
    default: //do something ;
```

If you have to use `$_POST` in the rest of your code you could do something like this at the $url where it is sent.

```
$_POST['pais'] = $_GET['pais'];
```

and so on.
Or, replace your `$_POST` references with `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear I have to use POST only because I am sending the values to a page that has huge amount of Post validation

Comment: fair enough :) , I think I will go with answer provided by transformer  .