# Browser not rendering redirect url

Tags: jsp, redirect

I have a request (originating from my localhost itself for now) that sends an `ajax` post request with `dataType` set to `json`. On the jsp, this `request` is parsed and based on some conditions, i do a redirect to another page (that resides on the server).

Now I understand a redirect is only for a resource that exists on a different server. However, even with .forward(), i am facing the same issue described below. 
My client side (again, this file resides on the server only for now) is:

Somefile.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


var payload = new Object();

payload.userInfo = new Object();

payload.userInfo.firstName = "Sam";
payload.userInfo.lastName = "Peter";
payload.userInfo.emailAddress = "speter@gmail.com";


payload.accountInfo = new Object();
payload.accountInfo.accountId = "12321";
payload.accountInfo.agentName = "Harry";
payload.accountInfo.terminalId = "1322";

payload.locale = "en-US";
payload.loggedIn = "true";


var payloadjson = JSON.stringify(payload);


        $('#call').click(function ()
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:8280/Somepath/FormFiller.jsp", 
    //this is my servlet
        dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){      
                        $('#output').append(data);
                },
        data: {postData:payloadjson}
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Call Servlet" name="Call Servlet" id="call"/>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And on the server side: 
FormFiller.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONValue"%>


<%
//response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",     
request.getHeader("Origin"));

request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
response.setContentType("application/json");

JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)    
JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("postData"));

JSONObject userInfo = (JSONObject)   
JSONValue.parse(jsonObj.get("userInfo").toString());

JSONObject accountInfo = (JSONObject) 
JSONValue.parse(jsonObj.get("accountInfo").toString());
String locale = (String) jsonObj.get("locale");
String loggedIn = (String) jsonObj.get("loggedIn");

out.println(userInfo.get("firstName"));
out.println(userInfo.get("lastName"));
out.println(userInfo.get("emailAddress"));

out.println(accountInfo.get("accountId"));
out.println(accountInfo.get("agentName"));
out.println(accountInfo.get("terminalId"));

out.println(locale);
out.println(loggedIn);


if(loggedIn == "false") {

// Redirect to some site

}

else {

out.println(request.getContextPath());
// Redirect to some other site and fill the form
response.sendRedirect("/somepath/xxx/yyy/zzz"); // zzz is some html file
return;
}
%>
```

Though I get the `response` (when i look at the developer console on chrome), the response (the redirect page) is not rendered on the browser so i can see all the controls/labels etc visually.

I tried this also but the same issue (not able to see the response on the browser visually).

```
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/xxx/yyy/zzz").forward(request,  
    response);
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the meaning of `ajax`, It is to

> update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page

So in your case , if you are trying to render or redirect a view(page) . Simply make an http request instead of ajax call.

Incase of partial view , i advise you render it as ,,

```
 $('#output').html(data);
```

in your ajax success

Comment: OK. But $('#output').html(data) din't help too :( But now let me just try httprequest. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think a GET request will suffice in this case. A POST is unnecessary here as we are not creating/editing/deleting anything on the server based on the post request payload. 
I found this post - [How to redirect with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036684/jquery-redirect-with-post-data)

if, in case, we necessarily need a POST only here. For my use case, GET suffices. Thanks for all the help.