# How to redirect to another page and print an alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I need to redirect to another page and when it's loaded I need to print an alert("HELLO");

I think something like this:

```
$.load(path, function() {
    alert.log("HELLO");
});
```

I have just used `window.location` but it is incorrect, because by changing my url I can't print the `alert("HELLO")`;

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you have control over the `document` that you are redirecting to?

Comment: @guest271314 yep

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery()` alias for `.ready()` at the `document` that you are redirecting to?

Comment: That code is not going to redirect and there is no way to redirect a page and  fire off code in that page with code in your page.

Comment: You would need to pass a parameter to the next page, and server side scripting would have to generate the alert. Instead you could open up a child window, instead of redirecting, and then you could pop up an alert from your initial page. Let me know if you want to go this route.

Answer (score 2):

You can change page via `window.location` as you have tried, but if you want to alert something in another page, this page should contain the script with the alert. In your new page simply add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('HELLO');
})
```

Comment: I am guessing that what he really wants is to pass a message to the next page, and display an alert for that.  And of course that will require appending a parameter to the redirect, and server side scripting to handle it.

Comment: @DavidPm if so, here is the answer about passing parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036954/6053654