# jquery Post value to PHP webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a web page with a dropdown menu. The idea is when we click any option of the dropdown menu it open produccion.php with a POST parameter 'edicion'. This parameter I use to do a query in a Database.

At moment the problem is that it's open the produccion.php but I think that doesn't POST the value of the variable

Jquery code:

```
    $('#drEdicion a').click(function(event){
        alert($(this).text());

        var ed = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({  
            url:"produccio.php",  
            type:"POST",  
            data:{edicion: ed},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                window.location.href = 'produccio.php'
            }  
        });     

    });
```

Is it possible that the problem is when it's send via ajax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you are sending ajax to produccio.php and then redirect page again to produccio.php... Where is the logic?! Beside, when you second time reditect page to produccio.php then of course there is not POST data because at second time you do not send any POST data :/

Comment: @nospor I need only send a time, How do it?

Comment: Remove this `window.location.href = 'produccio.php'`

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a form `POST`, but with a hyperlink instead of a submit button?

Comment: Yes, I want to open produccion.php after selection option in dropdown button. With this option I do a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently `POST`ing the content of the hyperlink over to `produccio.php` via AJAX. When that call completes it is then redirecting the user to the same page but without the `POST`ed value. Based on your comment:

> I want to open produccion.php after selection option in dropdown button. With this option I do a query

it appears you actually want to open `produccio.php` with the `POST`ed value in the browser.

By far the easiest solution to the problem would be to alter the PHP code to accept the value of `edicion` from `$_GET["edicion"]` instead, and output your hyperlink as:

```
<a href="produccio.php?edicion=...">...</a>
```

This will also provide a better experience for users, especially if they have issues with JavaScript (or, for example, happen to be a search engine). However, if you're set on only using `$_POST`, the following code may - I've not tested this myself - allow this:

```
$('#drEdicion a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var ed = $(this).text();
    $('<form action="produccio.php" method="POST">' + 
          '<input type="hidden" name="edicion" value="' + ed + '" />' +
          '</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
});
```

(with credit to the top answer on [Dynamically create and submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003089/dynamically-create-and-submit-form))

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow code :

```
$('#drEdicion a').click(function(event){
        //alert($(this).text());
        event.preventDefault();
        var ed = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({  
            url:"produccio.php",  
            type:"POST",  
            data:{edicion: ed},  
            dataType:"html",  
            success:function(data){  
                //#dropdown-menu id show all produccio.php data
                $("#dropdown-menu").html(data);
            }  
        });     

});
```

produccio.php

```
<?php
   $edicion = $_POST['edicion'];
   //now you can able to access edicion post param
?>
```

HTML like this :

```
<div id="dropdown-menu"></div>
```