# Trying to Hide Javascript form

Tags: javascript

Ok I'm trying to auto login a guest account and it requires:

In header

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function guestLogin() { 
        document.form_login.username.value = 'guest'; 
        document.form_login.password.value = 'guest'; 
        document.form_login.submit(); 
    }
</script>
```

And

```
<form action="https://www.redcheetah.com/WebPrefex/" method="post" name="form_login">
    <input name="username" type="text" value="" />
    <input name="password" type="password" value="" />
    <input name="form_action" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

javascript:guestLogin();
```

How would I get the `javascript:guestLogin();` to work without having the Login form on the page.

Any Tips?

Thanks

Comment: This is confusing. Are you saying there is no login form in the body? Or are you saying that you don't want to show the login form if the user is already logged in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003089/dynamically-create-and-submit-form

Comment: I saying I need the form to be there for the javascript:guestLogin(); to work.. but i dont want to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the form to be on the page - if you can't create it on demand for whatever reason - then if you want `guestLogin` to work without the user seeing the form, you'll have to hide the form using CSS. It'll still be submittable, it just won't be visible:

```js
function guestLogin() {
  document.form_login.username.value = 'guest';
  document.form_login.password.value = 'guest';
  console.log('submitting');
  document.form_login.submit();
}
document.querySelector('div').onclick = guestLogin;
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.redcheetah.com/WebPrefex/" method="post" name="form_login">
  <input name="username" type="text" value="" />
  <input name="password" type="password" value="" />
  <input name="form_action" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<div>click to submit</div>
```