# How to treat Calendar as Form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a web app with a calendar page where users can select days.
I want the selected days to be posted to the server which will then render the next page based on the days. 
In order to do this, I need the calendar I created to be treated as a form. How do I do something like this. I initially was using an AJAX request since I could store the selected days info in an array, but the issue is that an AJAX request does not load a new page.
Your input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please insert your code to your question! Without code it's hard to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code available right now, but essentially I have a calendar that is rendered as a <table>. Somehow need to send the selected dates (available in an array) in a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "https://example.com/methd";
var date = document.getElementById("calendar");
var keyName = "dates";

date.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
  form.setAttribute("action", url);
  var inputField = document.createElement('input');
  inputField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  inputField.setAttribute("name", keyName);
  inputField.setAttribute("value", this.value);
  form.appendChild(inputfield);
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="calendar" />
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003089/dynamically-create-and-submit-form/8003119)

Comment: Oh nice this is pretty dope. So keyName would contain the list of dates?